# Simple conditional on embed variable in exp:channel:entries

Tags: channel-entries, parse-order

Trying to do this:

{exp:channel:entries channel="main{if embed:inttest=="yes"}_inttest{/if}" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination" status="{tv_status}"}

Am I misunderstanding the channel entries tag parse order? I've stuck to simple conditionals testing only a Stage 1 embed var (right?) so I thought this would work, but nope. Thanks in advance for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. This works:

{exp:channel:entries channel="main{if "{embed:inttest}"=="yes"}_inttest{/if}" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination" status="{tv_status}"}

¯\_(ツ)_/¯